# Reverse pusher - secret needed to receive, not send

Tags: websocket, messaging, observer-pattern, pusher

Pusher service works as illustrated here:

[image: Pusher diagram]

Does it make sense to use it in reverse direction (and switched data channels)? My use case is as follows:

- end users (actually mobile, not browser) send messages to Pusher via HTTP-based REST API
- my firewalled machine is connected to Pusher via WebSockets API, subscribes channel and receives messages in realtime

This way I can work with Sandbox plan (only 1 persistent connection is used) but mobile app must contain Puser app key.

From what I understand, anyone can use this key to register subscribe same message stream via websockets. Is there a reverse mode, where **receiving** messages requires knowing the secret? Maybe other service would suit better?

Answer (score 0):

A more secure solution would be for the mobile clients to use [client events](https://pusher.com/docs/client_events). Client events can only be triggered on [private channels](https://pusher.com/docs/private_channels) where the subscription to the channel has to be authenticated.The authentication requests should got to an HTTP endpoint that you control so that you can validate the subscription request.

You firewalled machine can either then have a WebSocket connection and receive the client events over that connection. Or it could receive the client events via [client event WebHooks](https://pusher.com/docs/webhooks#client_events) if it exposes an HTTP endpoint.